# Reading input on c++ server in real time

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, server

I want to write a server in C++, I would connect to this server via Netcat or Telnet. Server would send a menu to a client and client would navigate using the arrows to choose an option. My question is: how can I get char-messages in real time (not after clicking Enter) from client?

Comment: This is *operating system* specific. Standard C++ does not know about sockets or terminals. So **edit your question** to tell more, at least give the appropriate tag for your OS

Comment: Is your application GUI, console or a driver?

Comment: It's a console application.

Comment: _"It's a console application"_: on what platform/operating system?

Comment: Write your own client and use something like `ncurses` .

Comment: Depeding on just how real time you want to get, Here's a useful search term: "Nagle's algorithm".

Answer (score 1):

C++ standard library has no API for keyboard input. There is only API for streams, which do require pressing enter (or EOT).

Implementing direct keyboard input on POSIX shell is quite tricky, and I would instead recommend using an existing library.

In particular, an implementation of the curses library will have a [`getch`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getch) function that you can poll in a loop.